# 1 image vs 2 images side by side

Tags: html, css, image

Can some please tell me how to add 1 image side-by-side as shown in this image, I mean with complete responsiveness

[image: check the image here]

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 78vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.big-image {
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/nothing-better-than-sliding-into-bed-with-a-good-read-picture-id929998552?b=1&k=20&m=929998552&s=170667a&w=0&h=GkJP5lHXoyVLYDIa86G6stcyEvoaAgN7xBFqgrc3QH8=");
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.twoSmallImages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img1 {
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/nothing-better-than-sliding-into-bed-with-a-good-read-picture-id929998552?b=1&k=20&m=929998552&s=170667a&w=0&h=GkJP5lHXoyVLYDIa86G6stcyEvoaAgN7xBFqgrc3QH8=");
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 2px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.img2 {
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/nothing-better-than-sliding-into-bed-with-a-good-read-picture-id929998552?b=1&k=20&m=929998552&s=170667a&w=0&h=GkJP5lHXoyVLYDIa86G6stcyEvoaAgN7xBFqgrc3QH8=");
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 2px auto;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big-image"></div>
  <div class="twoSmallImages">
    <div class="img1"></div>
    <div class="img2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the code?

Comment: Pls refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://codepen.io/yogeskumar/pen/yLoWXwj  this is the code i tried

Comment: What do you want to happen when the aspect ratios of the images mean they won’t exactly fit given the aspect ratio of the container?

Answer (score 0):

First ask correct question, then use this code and change your customize.. and

```css
.box{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr;
  width: 600px;
  background:red;
  gap:1rem;
  padding: 1rem
}
.img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}
.img01{
 grid-column:1/2;
  grid-row:1/3
}
.img02{
 grid-column:2/3;
  grid-row:1/2
}
.img03{
 grid-column:2/3;
  grid-row:2/3
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="img img01" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/400" title="" alt="">
  <img class="img img02" src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/600/400" title="" alt="">
  <img class="img img03" src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/600/400" title="" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display `flex` or `grid`. In this example I have used `flex`. If you want to use `grid` then let me know. The code is responsive so click on full page to see the layout that you have requested.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.fragment {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.fragment:nth-child(2) {
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .fragment:nth-child(2) {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: .5rem;
  }
  .image {
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fragment">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/nothing-better-than-sliding-into-bed-with-a-good-read-picture-id929998552?b=1&k=20&m=929998552&s=170667a&w=0&h=GkJP5lHXoyVLYDIa86G6stcyEvoaAgN7xBFqgrc3QH8=" alt="image" />
  </div>

  <div class="fragment">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/smart-student-learning-using-internet-and-headphones-picture-id1128717611" alt="image" />
    </div>

    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/shopping-online-concept-shopping-service-on-the-online-web-with-by-picture-id1133980246" alt="image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This layout looks like a grid.

You can specify the grid template areas so that the big image covers basically two thirds of the width and the smaller images one third.

This snippet sets the size of the background images to cover so that the full grid looks like in the picture given in the question whatever the viewport size. However, this will of course not always show complete images and if it is important to have complete images whatever the various aspect ratios then go back to using contain though you will sometimes get space either top and bottom or at the sides of an image.

Note that the HTML and the CSS have been simplified to make things clearer.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 78vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'a a b'
    'a a c';
  grid-gap: 1vw;
}
.container div {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.big-image {
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/nothing-better-than-sliding-into-bed-with-a-good-read-picture-id929998552?b=1&k=20&m=929998552&s=170667a&w=0&h=GkJP5lHXoyVLYDIa86G6stcyEvoaAgN7xBFqgrc3QH8=");
  grid-area: a;
}

.img1 {
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/nothing-better-than-sliding-into-bed-with-a-good-read-picture-id929998552?b=1&k=20&m=929998552&s=170667a&w=0&h=GkJP5lHXoyVLYDIa86G6stcyEvoaAgN7xBFqgrc3QH8=");
  background-color: #fff;
  grid-area: b;
}

.img2 {
  background: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/nothing-better-than-sliding-into-bed-with-a-good-read-picture-id929998552?b=1&k=20&m=929998552&s=170667a&w=0&h=GkJP5lHXoyVLYDIa86G6stcyEvoaAgN7xBFqgrc3QH8=");
  background-color: brown;
  grid-area: c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big-image"></div>
    <div class="img1"></div>
    <div class="img2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got it right, thanks for the answer, but you have used the cover as background-size, is it possible to make it responsive when it's specified to contain rather then cover

Comment: It will be responsive in the sense it will take up the space you have set for the container but you will have gaps above and below or at the sides of the images. This is inevitable when the aspect ratios of the images make it impossible to fit them exactly as required in whatever the container’s aspect ratio is. You have set the container’s aspect ratio to 78vw/50vh so it is different on different viewports.